# Angular Typescript Save previous value of a variable to restore data

Tags: angular, typescript, variables

I'm doing some operation on a variable modifying its data but I'd like to save it in another variable to be able to restore it if needed.
I tried to declare my two variables in my class as below

```
user: User;
savedUser: User;
```

and to assign them in the constructor

```
this.user = data.user;
this.savedUser = data.user;
```

I have a function in the OnInit block that does the user operation

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.formatUser(this.user);
}

formatUser(user:User): User{
   user.name = 'Peter';
   user.age = 18;
   return user;
}

resetUser(): void {
   this.user = this.savedUser;
}
```

The reset function is not working as it seems the "savedUser" variable is also updated when the line `this.user = this.formatUser(this.user);` runs

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone deep the initial user object instead of simply storing it in another variable. Every time you update savedUser just do like below.

```
const savedUser = {...data.user}
```

OR

```
const savedUser = Object.assign({}, data.user);
```

OR

```
const savedUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.user));
```

You can refer to following article for more context on the above methods;

https://vkglobal.hashnode.dev/js-clone-object

OR

```
const savedUser = ._cloneDeep(data.user); // to use this you need to import external loadash library.
```

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand the question, but should this:

```
gOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.formatUser(this.user);
}
```

be this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.savedUser = this.formatUser(this.user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the reference is the same for both the user & savedUser variable. You can fix this by creating a copy in the constructor of the object:

```
this.user = data.user;
this.savedUser = Object.assign({}, this.user)
```